# Automounting USB drive on boot

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount

I'm trying to mount a usb harddrive on boot on my freshly installed raspbian. I added the following line to my /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=73a104af-6ada-4956-b1e2-90bfdc08aba5 /mnt/Platte ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

However, the drive wont mount. I always have to run

```
sudo mount -a
```

for it to show up as mounted. Any ideas what i could possibly have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the auto option, to say fstab to auto mount it at startup

```
    UUID=73a104af-6ada-4956-b1e2-90bfdc08aba5 /mnt/Platte ext4         defaults,noatime,auto 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use crontab:

`sudo crontab -e`

then enter this at the bottom of the file:

`@reboot sudo mount -a /dev/LOC /mnt/Platte`

where LOC is the location of the partition, EX: sda1

The way to find the location is by removing all over flash drives and then enter:

`sudo ls /dev/sd*1`

which will return the location of the flash drive.

**EDIT**

You could still use the UUID to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I fixed mine in following way,

Get the uuid of the external hard drive with following command

```
sudo blkid
```

Add the entry into fstab so that when you restart the raspberry device it is auto mounted every time

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

> UUID=0A423D084xxxxxx /mnt/data ntfs defaults,noatime,auto 0 0

**Some explanation for above command** - I mounted it to **/mnt/data** directory. ( You need to create it first if doesn't exist with **sudo mkdir /mnt/data** ) Mine was a **NTFS** format. You might try only the **defaults** option. I added **noatime** and **auto** to experiment a few things. You can check more details about it on internet.

Some Raspberry device ( including mine ) needs one more addition ( optional, try only if above doesn't work ), after above command, add a **5 seconds delay** to loading the device as sometimes the Raspberry OS loads faster than external drive and external hard drive loads a little slower and need more time to start, in this case the external drive isn't auto mounted and it is skipped with an error at the start. Add the following property/value to the end of your **cmdline.txt inside /boot folder**

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

Add

> rootdelay=5

Hope it helps!