# Mounting USB on boot causes error on boot

Tags: pi-4, mount, fstab

I am attempting to mount a usb drive to a specific directory at boot time so that it's mapped to the same directory each time. I read this article, [Automounting USB drive on boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36824/automounting-usb-drive-on-boot), that says to add it to /etc/fstab

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=bf444af9-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=bf444af9-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

I tried both PARTUUID and UUID, same results both times.

Here's what I've tried:

```
PARTUUID=b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
PARTUUID=fc69e031-8593-4c67-9cf9-c364d0166117 /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
UUID=b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
UUID=fc69e031-8593-4c67-9cf9-c364d0166117 /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
```

When I restart, it is giving this error:

> Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.

I got out of this by modifying the cmdline.txt and adding bash.

I did a `blkid` to see my usb drive UUID. Here is what I got:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="6284-658D" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="bf444af9-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="3a324232-335f-4617-84c3-d4889840dc93" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bf444af9-02"
/dev/sda2: UUID="b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="fc69e031-8593-4c67-9cf9-c364d0166117"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="bf444af9" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="4792d598-bd1e-4784-99a5-27db1f5d937b"
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot get this usb drive to mount at boot up to a specific directory.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Not sure as my mind is not into fstab tonight - first guess is the partition is not ext4.  For testing new entries in fstab I use `sudo mount -a` once I've added the line in.  Once that reports no errors and works I feel safe to reboot :-). Also add `nofail` to the line - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53456/what-is-the-difference-between-nobootwait-and-nofail-in-fstab. It would help to know what works in the file and what you are adding :-). Though this is on a Raspberry Pi - its actually a Linux issue so it should be closed here and moved (daft I know)

Comment: Add a nofail option to your fstab entry - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/14365/mount-an-external-drive-at-boot-time-only-if-it-is-plugged-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel [the article you followed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36824/automounting-usb-drive-on-boot) is not a particularly good one.

The following `/etc/fstab` entry always works for me:

```
LABEL=PASSPORT2TB /mnt/Passport2TB ext4 rw,user,nofail 0 0
```

Of course you will need to substitute the LABEL that identifies your USB drive, and create a *mount point* that suits you better than `/mnt/Passport2TB`. If your drive is formatted in something other than `ext4`, change that to match.

If you want to edit the LABEL for your USB drive, there are several ways to do this:

1. plug it into your Mac/Windows/Linux PC, and change it w/ the GUI
2. you can also use the CLI with a [procedure similar to this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194510/how-to-edit-label-of-usb-drive)

Why use `LABEL` instead of `UUID`? How many drives are you mounting on an RPi? Do you really need 32 hex characters (2<sup>36</sup> bits) to keep up with all your disk drives? Which is easier to remember? Have you read the section `Indicating the device and filesystem` in `man mount`?

You have chosen `/mnt/usb2` as your mount point. That should work, but have you also created the folder/dir you'll use for a *mount point*? Using the example above:

```bsh
$ mkdir /mnt/Passport2TB
```

After you've done all of this, it's time to test:

```bsh
$ sudo mount -av
```

All should be well. Now, if you want to experiment with other options (`defaults`, `umask`), edit the line you just inserted in `/etc/fstab` to add **one** of them. Then `umount` the USB drive, and run `sudo mount -av` again. Repeat as necessary until you've got it right.

If you're still having problems, run the command `lsblk --fs`, and post that instead of `blkid` results. Why use `lsblk` instead of `blkid`? If you actually read `man blkid` you'll see this passage:

> Note  that  blkid  reads  information  directly  from devices and for non-root users it returns cached unverified information.  It is better to use lsblk --fs to get a user-friendly overview of filesystems and  devices. lsblk(8) is also easy to use in scripts.  blkid is mostly designed for system services and to test libblkid functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the bash command a bash executable and place it in `/etc/init.d`

such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount foo /dev/foo_bar
```